# Limit of a Permutation: $P(N,n)$ for $n\ll N$

Tags: asymptotics, permutations

I'm trying to prove that, for $N\gg n$,

$P(N,n)=\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}\approx N^{n}$

I've tried two approaches,

### 1

$\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}=\frac{N\left(N-1\right)\cdots\left(N-n+1\right)\left(N-n\right)!}{\left(N-n\right)!}=N(N-1)\cdots(N-n+1)=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(N-i\right)$

I now understand that I have $n$ factors involving $N$ minus something
which is to be small compared with $N$ so that I could say it approximates
$N^{n}$ . But I should be able to state it formally.

### 2

$\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}=\exp\left(\ln\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}\right)=\exp\left(\ln N!-\ln\left(N-n\right)!\right)$

Doing the stirling approximation I get,

$\approx\exp\left(N\ln N-N-\left(N-n\right)\ln\left(N-n\right)+N-n\right)=N^{N}(N-n)^{n-N}e^{-n}$

Comment: I don't think there is much left to prove here really. If you continue your first approach it is clear that since $N-i\approx N$ for all $i$, that $\prod \limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(N-i\right) \approx N^n$

Comment: I guess n->0 removes n from the equation which you dont want.

try binomial for (N-n)^n-N

Comment: you're right @rbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Stirling approximation like this: $N!=N^Ne^{-N}$. Then you get:

$\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}  \approx \frac{e^{-n}N^N}{(N-n)^{N-n}}=N^n e^{-n}\left(\frac{N}{N-n}\right)^{N-n}$

Then you can see that $\left(\frac{N}{N-n}\right)^{N-n}\approx e^n$ which solves your problem.

Comment: I had to work the last step but I saw it. Thanks.

Comment: I also saw I made a careless mistake on the last step of my second approach: I was summing the terms where they should be multiplied. So I end up with the same result you did. I'll edit my question